# How can I split an ArrayList into two new ArrayLists?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections, split

I have on `ArrayList` which contains data like this: `13-ITEM,14-ITEM,15-ITEMGROUP` (with a hyphen (-) as the separator).
I want to split this list into two new `ArrayLists`:

- **ArrayList-1** containing the ids: `[13,14,15..]`
- **ArrayList-2** containing the Strings: `[ITEM,ITEM,ITEMGROUP...]`

I am new to Java. Thanks in advance.

Comment: split it using - and add both indexes value to different array lists

Comment: If it is possible in your case, try to use Map instead of List. Number would be a key and String will be vaule.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`String#indexOf(char)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-) to find the index in the `String` of the separator then use `String#substring` to extract the sub strings, as next:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("13-ITEM","14-ITEM","15-ITEMGROUP");
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>(list.size());
List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>(list.size());
for (String s : list) {
    int index = s.indexOf('-');
    // Add what we have before the separator in list1
    list1.add(s.substring(0, index));
    // Add what we have after the separator in list2
    list2.add(s.substring(index + 1));
}
System.out.printf("List 1 = %s, List 2 = %s%n", list1, list2);
```

**Output:**

```
List 1 = [13, 14, 15], List 2 = [ITEM, ITEM, ITEMGROUP]
```

Comment: Thanks it helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

Split each entry and add the parts to the different lists. If the texts contain more `-`s, then use substring.

```
ArrayList<String> input = ...
List<String> output1 = new ArrayList<>(input.size());
List<String> output2 = new ArrayList<>(input.size());

for(String item:input){
  String[] splitted = item.split("-");
  output1.add(splitted[0]);
  output2.add(splitted[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("13-ITEM", "14-ITEM", "15-ITEMGROUP");
list.stream().map(p -> p.substring(0, p.indexOf('-'))).forEach(System.out::println);
list.stream().map(p -> p.substring(p.indexOf('-') + 1)).forEach(System.out::println);
```

If you split your concerns like this (each list is created using different logic), you will have a possibility to encapsulate code further. For example you can add some exception handling.

```
private static Function<String, String> getFunction() {
    return new Function<String, String>() {
        @Override
        public String apply(String p) {
            return p.substring(0, p.indexOf('-'));
        }
    };
}
```